# How do you create a pie chart of subitems using a crossfiltered powered dc.js chart?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

Suppose I have a list of customers with their orders:

```
const customers = [
  { id: 1, orders: [{ products: ["apple", "banana"] }, { products: ["apple"] }] },
  { id: 2, orders: [{ products: ["strawberry"] }] },
  { id: 3, orders: [{ products: ["apple"] }, { products: ["strawberry"] }] },
  { id: 4, orders: [] }
]
```

I would like to see a pie chart that shows a slice for every single product available. When filtering, I would like to click on "apple" and filter by the customers who ordered apples at any point in time.

I'm currently able to render the pie chart but it shows every possible combination of products as a slice.

Meaning, my pie chart has a slice for `apple, banana`, `strawberry`, `apple, strawberry`, and `none`.

This isn't what I'm going for. I did this by creating the dimension:

```
const dimension = crossfilter.dimension((customer: Customer) => {

    const productList = customer.orders.flatMap(x => x.products)
    const products = new Set<string>(productList);
    const result = [...products ];
    if (result.length === 0) return "none";

    return result;
})

const group = dimension.group();
```

The filtering behavior works correctly but the pie charts slices are not sustainable in this way.

EDIT: I added a js fiddle that demonstrates the situation a little more clearly: https://jsfiddle.net/qcaod71z/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension

You can now set the second argument specify that the return value is an array.

```
const dimension = crossfilter.dimension((customer: Customer) => {
    const productList = customer.orders.flatMap(x => x.products)
    const products = new Set<string>(productList);
    const result = [...products ];
    if (result.length === 0) return "none";

    return result;
}, true)
```

Comment: I had to switch the `"none"` to `["none"]` but it worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that's because you are returning an array, the `result` variable.
You can extract products in a single list:

```js
const customers = [
  { id: 1, orders: [{ products: ["apple", "banana"] }, { products: ["apple"] }] },
  { id: 2, orders: [{ products: ["strawberry"] }] },
  { id: 3, orders: [{ products: ["apple"] }, { products: ["strawberry"] }] },
  { id: 4, orders: [] }
];

const allProducts = [...customers.reduce((s, a) => {
  const customerProducts = a.orders.flatMap(o => o.products);
  customerProducts.forEach(p => s.add(p));
  if (customerProducts.length === 0)
    s.add("none");
  return s;
}, new Set())];

console.log(allProducts);
```

Or you can:

```js
const customers = [
  { id: 1, orders: [{ products: ["apple", "banana"] }, { products: ["apple"] }] },
  { id: 2, orders: [{ products: ["strawberry"] }] },
  { id: 3, orders: [{ products: ["apple"] }, { products: ["strawberry"] }] },
  { id: 4, orders: [] }
]
const flattenedData = [];

customers.forEach(customer => {
    customer.orders.forEach(order => {
        order.products.forEach(product => {
            flattenedData.push({
                customerId: customer.id,
                product: product
            });
        });
    });
});

console.log(flattenedData);
```

And the setup `crossfilter`:

```
const crossfiltered = crossfilter(flattenedData);
const productDimension = crossfiltered.dimension(d => d.product);
const productGroup = productDimension.group();
```

Comment: So I can see this approaches working in isolation but I have many different types of  dimensions to consider that have already been setup. For instance, consider customer gender, age, etc. I would like to be able to crossfilter customers who are male, aged 35, who have ordered apples.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle link to the original post.